# Send notification from Google App Engine Task to UI

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, task

My Google App Engine JSP needs to perform a lengthy processing so it adds the task to Task Queue, then refreshes every 30 sec waiting for task completion. How the task can let JSP know about its status? I tried to use session but it seems session objects are not shared between JSP and tasks. I tried to throw exceptions from the task in case if it fails hoping to launch error page (I did configure error-page in web.xml) but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this kind of problems is implement some kind of "Web Hook" where when tasks is finished it will call back the JSP.

Another option is to implement AJAX, where this asynchronous call will check the status of the task then will update the UI as necessary.

If you can give more context into the question it would be better.

Comment: I am running on Google App Engine. There is no way I know to add web hook or use AJAX to communicate with the task that runs from the Google App Engine queue

Comment: Queue is basically a "queue" that alls on a URL. What you need to do is to  call back to the JSP when task is done. That would call a fresh JSP btw. If you don't want to do this, what you can do is to make sure that before the URL / method that queue called returns you will call Datastore to store a status object, about this specific queued task, either STARTED, WORKING and DONE, String values. Then your JSP will need to java some Ajax call to check the status once in a while, e.g. every 1-2 seconds.